# What means sign $ before values in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

What means sign $ before values in pl/sql?

Comment: _"$ before values"_ or before *identifiers* or before *"schema object names"*?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet where you saw this so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

`$` in PL/SQL likely either means an [Inquiry Directive](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#CHDIDJFE) or a [Preprocessor Control Token](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#CHDFBBCB).  Those are tools for conditional compilation.

Some other uses of `$` are for naming schema objects (but not for the first character), and for a regular expression anchor in a row pattern match element.  The new 12c row pattern matching features adds some annoying ambiguity into even a simple lexical analysis of PL/SQL.

Here's an example with all 4 uses put together.  This is valid code in 12c, although it doesn't do anything useful.

```
alter session set plsql_ccflags = 'inq_dir_test:1';

declare
    v_test number;
begin
    select $$inq_dir_test inq_dir_test$$
    into v_test
    from dual
    match_recognize(
        measures x.dummy dummy
        pattern(
            ^$|
            x{$$inq_dir_test}|
            x{$IF 1=1 $THEN 1 $END}
        )
        define x as (1=1)
    );
end;
/
```